# How to wait for networking on login after reboot?

Tags: raspbian, networking, bash, login

Upon reboot and login, I want to check to see if a remote computer (10.1.0.53) is listening for UDP on port 2222. I have tried adding the following line to ~/.bashrc (later, I tried ~/.profile, with the same result):

```
nc -z -u -v 10.1.0.53 2222
```

Upon reboot, I get the message:

> *nc: connect to 10.1.0.53 port 2222 (UDP) failed: Network is unreachable*

If I immediately try `source .bashrc` at the prompt, it succeeds and outputs:

> *Connection to 10.1.0.53 2222 port [udp/*] succeeded!*

How do I make netcat wait until the network is reachable? (10.1.0.53 *is* listening the entire time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Raspbian, you can use raspi-config to delay boot until the network is up.

start raspi-config with the following:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then select option **4 Wait for network at boot**

then select **Slow Wait for network connection before completing boot**

click **Ok**

Then **Finish**

Finally reboot.

Comment: Is it possible to edit a file by hand instead of running raspi-config?

Comment: yes, check the raspi-config source that is all it is doing. though raspi-config is easier and far less prone to error.

Comment: What is this option doing under the hood?

Comment: Scratch user here, I can't seem to find the option on raspi-config - but if you click on the Raspberry Pi symbol on the taskbar (application menu) and then 'Preferences' -> 'Raspberry Pi Configuration' you can see the option 'wait for network'

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/latest-raspbian-update/

Comment: @JasonFloyd The files `raspi-config` modifies are shown in this part of the code: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/060cc692adb0d9489aff42fbceb6aa641365f42f/raspi-config#L1033-L1038.  Alternatively, you can avoid modifying files manually or having to interact with raspi-config by running `raspi-config nonint do_boot_wait 0`